# Spatie Laravel 9: send email notification to Users with roles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I got everything working in terms of sending emails and templating. Now I want to replace the static `to: email@test.com` with users' email with specific roles.

I have this code written:

```
 public function envelope()
    {
        return new Envelope(
            from: 'amushref@hsse.co',
            to: [
                User::with("roles")->whereHas("roles", function($q) {
                    $q->whereIn("id", [
                        1, // Super Admin
                        6, // Admin
                        2, // Security Supervisor
                        5, // Security Manager
                    ]);
                })->get('email')
            ],
            subject: 'New Incident: ' . str_pad($this->record->ir_number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT) .
                ' - ' .
                $this->record->caseTypeRelationship->name .
                ' - ' . $this->record->locationRelationship->name,
        );
    }
```

I've made `to:` as an array to include emails of the provided roles (`id`). I get an error saying that the address are not correct/doesn't exist. What is the proper way to fetch emails of users of the selected roles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you do not need to include `roles` if you don't need them.  It's introducing an additional query which you should avoid.

Secondly, your `->get('email')` is returning a `Collection` of users with only the `email` field.  You probably want to convert that to an array to pass it on to the `Envelope`.

Thirdly, you have wrapped the output of your `->get('email')` which in itself is already a collection in an array of its own, making your email sit a level too deep.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
to: User::whereHas("roles", function($q) {
  $q->whereIn("id", [1, 6, 2, 5]);
})->pluck('email')->toArray(),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the list of emails with the following and assign it to an array:

```
$emails = User::role(['Super Admin', 'Admin', 'Security Supervisor', 'Security Manager'])
                     ->pluck('email')->toArray();
```

then change your `to: $emails`